# How do I start MongoDB in a script?

Tags: bash, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a script to start different things. Whenever I add the below to the script and run it, I get a message: "mongod: unrecognized service". I can use it in the terminal, but not through the script.

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

mongod/mongodb depends on Linux version

Answer (score 0):

I got it to start just using sudo service mongod start. The .sh file was created in Windows. Once I deleted it and created a .sh file in Linux, it ran.